# Image segmentation with very small dataset

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation

Given an image of puzzles on some background (depends on difficulty of the task), recognize the number of puzzles on it and classify each puzzle on the image (for each puzzle tell how many peninsulas and bays it has)

Background can be red
[image: (example)]

Or colored
[image: example]

I managed to solve (or almost solve) easy version of this problem (red background) using opencv (otsu thresholding -> dilating -> some smoothing convolutions -> findContours and then pass contours to some classifier)

But I have serious difficulties when trying to solve a complicated version. This

[image]
is the best I have achieved so far using otsu thresholding and erode + dilate. It appears that this thresholding method does not work so good for hard background.

My dataset is very small (less than 10 images), so i guess its not possible to use some deep learning segmentation techniques. But may be i can use some pre-trained models?
This is my first CV problem, so i dont have much knowledge about it. I'm kinda out of ideas and asking you to help me.

Thanks!

Comment: On your second image. Check out the size of your Blobs of Interest. They appear quite big in comparison to the rest of the "noise". Why don't you filter your blobs based on area? The filter won't give you a perfect segmentation, since some of your blobs are broken, but is a nice approximation. Further, you can try to merge the bits of blobs after you have filtered the smaller ones!

Comment: Use color thresholding via cv2.inRange() on a nearly constant color background (like your first example) to threshold your image rather than OTSU thresholding. The use morphology to clean up the smaller regions. Then get contours and filter by area if you need to remove smaller or larger regions.

Comment: The image with constant background is easy to solve but for colored one it seems difficult.

Comment: Also, on the second image, try a median/average filter, then an HSV conversion. As suggested, perform thresholding by searching for high-valued pixels on the V channel and then perform area filtering. This should give you a nice segmentation mask. BTW, I like your user name. That's the first thing I feel when I wake up.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use shape based matching. For instance you compute gradients for each shape for each rotation angle and scale you will ise with some small step. Then train neural network detector.
For implementation instance check: https://github.com/meiqua/shape_based_matching